# clang-format indents X macros

Tags: c++, formatting, clang-format, x-macros

I'm using c-style X macros to create two way enums like this:

```
namespace ns
{
#define CFG_INT_TABLE                                                          \
    X(CFG_1, "cfg_1", invalid_int_value),                                      \
    X(CFG_2, "cfg_2", invalid_int_value),                                      \
    X(CFG_3, "cfg_3", 10)

#define X(a,b,c) a
    enum class IntegerConfigs : int
    {
        CFG_INT_TABLE,
        TOTAL_ELEMENTS
    }
#undef X

#define X(a,b,c) b
   array ...
#undef X
    [...]
}
```

however when running clang-format, It indents the lines like this:

```
#define CFG_INT_TABLE                                                           \
    X(CFG_1, "cfg_1", invalid_int_value),                                       \
        X(CFG_2, "cfg_2", invalid_int_value),                                   \
        X(CFG_3, "cfg_3", 10)
```

I couldn't understand from clang-format's options how to indent the code properly, I prefer a fix that only changes `.clang-format` file and not the code itself if possible.

this is my `.clang-format` file:

```
BasedOnStyle: GNU
AccessModifierOffset: -2
ColumnLimit: 100
IndentWidth: 4
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
FixNamespaceComments: true
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatements
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: Empty
NamespaceIndentation: All
BreakConstructorInitializers: AfterColon
ReferenceAlignment: Left
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
Standard: c++20
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: true
  AfterControlStatement: false
  AfterEnum: true
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterNamespace: true
  AfterStruct: true
  AfterUnion: true
  BeforeCatch: false
  BeforeElse: false
  IndentBraces: false
```

Thank you!

Comment: What happens when you use any random macro with `\` line breaks?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, this X macro could be improved is various ways. Drop the commas and consider passing the X macro as a parameter to the list macro. That way it turns much more flexible and generic.

Comment: If there are only 2 lines, it tries to put them together on 1 line if possible.
If there are more than 2 lines, it indents once from the first line.
And thank you about the suggestion, I will implement it.

Comment: Maybe a quick & dirty work-around would be to include a single empty line with nothing but a backslash after the `#define` line?

Comment: @Lundin didn't work sadly... I ended up using `// clang-format off` comments. Thank you for the help!